# What is the Python equivalent of LINQ OfType<T>() (in .NET)

Tags: python, linq, casting, equivalent

I am trying to get a single `Handler` of a specific custom type `MemoryListHandler` in the `logger.handlers` collection.

With .NET I would simply use the following LINQ extension, which filters element and returns only those of type `MemoryListHandler`:

```
logger.handlers.OfType<MemoryListHandler>().SingleOrDefault()
```

What would be the most elegant equivalent in Python?

My current (not very neat) attempt is:

```
next((handler for handler in logger.handlers if handler is MemoryListHandler), None)
```

Comment: I'd say you already have the best solution... You could hide it in a function or something but it doesn't get much better than that.

Comment: "is" is for object identity test so I think isinstance(handler, MemoryListHandler) would be the proper test.

Answer (score 1):

Python is dynamically typed, therefore you might not need to convert anything.

However, in some cases you still might need to convert, say, int to string :

```
  map(lambda x: str(x), [1, 2, 3])
```

Or, given your function accepts only one argument, just pass the function alone :

```
  map(str, [1, 2, 3])
```

Update

```
 filter(lambda x: type(x) == YourClass, [your_array])
```

Comment: You don't need the `lambda`; just pass `str` as the first argument to `map`, like so: `map(str, [1, 2, 3])`.

Comment: It seems my question may not have been clear enough, I have reformulated it a bit.

Comment: @Erwin Mayer, use the operaror 'type' or method  "__ class __" on a variable

Answer (score 1):

You might try the `index` method.

```
try:
    lh = logger.handlers
    x = lh[lh.index(MemoryListHandler)]
except ValueError:
    x = some_default_value
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python the `is` operator tests identity NOT type like it does in c#. You want `isinstance` for your test -- which will also work with subtypes of the target_type you're looking for.

Using the Python REPL to illustrate the difference between `is` and `isinstance`:

```
>>> s = ""
>>> s is str
False
>>> isinstance(s, str)
True
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self):
...         pass
...
>>> f = Foo()
>>> g = Foo()
>>> f is g
False
>>> f is Foo
False
>>> g is Foo
False
>>> x = f
>>> f is x
True
>>> g is x
False
```

Your own expression is pretty close to what you want. You can hide it behind a method:

```
def first_of_type(xs, target_type):
    return next((x for x in xs if isinstance(x, target_type)), None)
```

Usage becomes short and sweet:

```
first_of_type(logger.handlers, MemoryListHandler)
```

Note: addition of type hints and doc comments would help usability.